# Can I give chained host paths in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a scenario where I have ansible deployed on one node (Say `node1`) and wan't to control another node (say `node2`).

But the problem is, I cannot directly `ssh` into `node2` from `node1`. Instead I need to `ssh` into another machine (say `node1.5`) and then from there I need to again `ssh` into `node2`.

Is it possible to give this kind of path to ansible, so that when I need to control `node2` it will automatically follow the path to reach `node2`?

`Node1 (Controller)` -> ***ssh*** -> `Node1.5` -> ***ssh*** -> `Node2 (Host)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible uses your default ssh config (or a separate one as defined by you in `ansible.cfg`), so you are able to define such proxy rules per ssh:

```
Host Node2
  ProxyCommand ssh -q Node1.5 nc %h %p
```